# Build table in Excel By Pulling Data from Different Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a table on the "Efficiency" sheet by pulling data from different sheets numbered 1,2,3,4.... The table that I am trying to build has 8 columns. One of them is the date. The date is only in one cell of the sheet, cell G4 and it is the same spot on every sheet. The other columns come from columns B,C,D,E,F,O and Q, starting from row 9 downwards. The size of the columns can change as we go from sheet 1 to 2 to 3 etc. I want to copy only the data and nothing else. There is some formatting up to row 20, but do not want to copy a fixed number of rows, only as much as there is data. When I paste this information into the "Efficiency" sheet, I want only the data, not the formatting. I also want the length of the date column to match the length of the other data points and the "date" sheet that it was taken from. I also want a title row, only once, on the first row of the table being built and the items are "Date" and row 8 of the B,C,D,E,F,O and Q, columns (this is the same on every "date" sheet, but only need it once for table header on the "Efficiency" sheet). Would anyone be able to help me realize this please?

Thanks

'

```
Sub DataTable()

Dim wsTable As Worksheet
Set wsTable = Worksheets("Efficiency") 'change as needed

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Select Case ws.Name

        Case Is = "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"

            With ws

                Dim rngData As Range
                Set rngData = Union(.Range("B:F"), .Range("O:O"), .Range("Q:Q"))

                Dim lRow As Long
                Dim rCheck As Range
                For Each rCheck In Intersect(rngData, .Rows(1))

                    If .Cells(.Rows.Count, rCheck.Column).End(xlUp).Row > lRow Then
                         lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, rCheck.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                     End If

                Next

                        Dim dDate As Date
                        dDate = .Range("G4").Value


                    With wsTable

                    .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(lRow, 1).Value = dDate
                    ws.Range("B9:F" & lRow).Copy
                    .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial x1PasteValues
                    ws.Range("O9:O" & lRow).Copy
                    .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial x1PasteValues
                    ws.Range("Q9:O" & lRow).Copy
                    .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial x1PasteValues

                End With

            End With

    End Select

Next

End Sub
```

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do.  I think you are trying to make it a little bit more difficult than necessary.  Here's some code that I created using some loops to get what you want.  It copies the date of the sheet into a variable.   Next, I put the word Date in the first column and made the headers columns B - I.  You can adjust accordingly.

```
Dim rowDate As Date

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
rowDate = Cells(4, 7)

Range("B9").Select
' Copy the header rows & make the word Date the first column
Sheets("Efficiency").Range("A1") = "Date"
Range("B8:F8").Copy
Sheets("Efficiency").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("O8").Copy
Sheets("Efficiency").Range("H1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("Q8").Copy
Sheets("Efficiency").Range("I1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

' Cycle throught the sheets and copy the data  
' Each array item is the sheet name.

Dim SheetArray(4) As String
SheetArray(0) = "Sheet1"
SheetArray(1) = "Sheet2"
SheetArray(2) = "Sheet3"
SheetArray(3) = "Sheet4"

Dim EffRow As Integer  ' Keep track of the correct row on the Efficiency sheet
Dim EffCell As String   ' Track the cell for effeciency
EffRow = 2
For i = 0 To 3

    Sheets(SheetArray(i)).Select
    rowDate = Cells(4, 7)
    Range("B9").Select

    ' Loop until a blank cell is reached
    Do While Not (IsEmpty(ActiveCell))
        EffCell = "A" & EffRow
        Sheets("Efficiency").Range(EffCell) = rowDate
        Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 5)).Copy
        EffCell = "B" & EffRow
        Sheets("Efficiency").Range(EffCell).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Copy
        EffCell = "H" & EffRow
        Sheets("Efficiency").Range(EffCell).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        EffCell = "I" & EffRow
        Sheets("Efficiency").Range(EffCell).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        EffRow = EffRow + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
Next i
```

End Sub

Hopefully this steers you in the right direction.

Comment: It's beautiful! Thank you! Work well